# Q:python: why is my char considered as a str?

Tags: python, string

I just started python and I'm stuck on a stupid error but I don't understand why it's not working

```
def encryption(str1):
    i = 0
    for x in str1:
        if (x >= 'a' and x <= 'z' or x >= 'A' and x <= 'Z'):
            str1[i] = str1[i] + 3 % 26 #str[i] = x + 3 % 26
        i+=1
    return str1
```

when I execute the program I got this error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str.

Can someone explain me why str[i] - 23 is considered as a str ? To me I'm just modifying the ascii value of a char.

Comment: this isn't C, try `ord(str1[i])` to get ASCII value of the character. Why mixing indices with `x` ? and the error seems to be somewhere else...

Comment: and fix your indentation before posting.

Comment: Keep in mind that strings are immutable

Comment: I mixed both because I basically tried just x then just str1[I] then i twisted both etc etc ... ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in python are not arrays like in C. They are immutable, ie 
you can't make in place changes to the string. Your options are turn 
the string into a list (similar to a c array) or make a new empty string
and concatenate each encrypted letter onto it (this will probably be faster). Ord converts string to ascii number and chr converts the inverse.
the isalpha method tests true iff the character is in {a-z A-Z}

```
str1 = 'this is a test string!@#$@#$@'

def encryption(str1):
    new_string = ''
    for character in str1:
        if character.isalpha():
            new_string += chr(ord(character) + 3 % 26)
        else:
            new_string += character
    return new_string

print(encryption(str1))
```

Comment: Oh ok, well I think that i'll do a big python string training session, I didn't though that there's so much difference between python and C strings. Well, thank you.

Comment: The main difference is the immutibility. You can index a string, just like in C but you can't change individual character elements. if you want to turn it into a pseudo C array do a list comprehension array = [ x for x in string ], then to zip it back up after changes use "".join(array). Although, the method in my answer will be faster and more pythonic.

Comment: yea I'm not doing python to imitate c so I'll try to reason like you.